# Setting mysql as shell

Tags: mysql, linux

I have a user on my machine that is only supposed to run mysql. Is there any way that I can set the shell of that user to mysql and login using password and username?

I know how to change the shell to the mysql binary

```
usermod -s /usr/bin/mysql
```

That is working indeed, only I can't provide a username/password in the program. Usually user/pw are given as

```
mysql -u $USER -p
```

I can not provide parameters for a shell as in

```
usermod -s "/usr/bin/mysql -u $USER -p" # Does not work!
```

Also using a simple shell-script as shell does not work:

```
#!/bin/sh # mysqlShell
/usr/bin/mysql -u $USER -p
----
usermod -s mysqlShell # does not work
```

So how can I provide parameters to a program I use as a shell for a user?

---

Thanks to [Tom Regner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/594138/tom-regner) I could figure out a solution using .my.cnf containing

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=$user
password=$pass
disable-auto-rehash
```

where mysql is set to the shell. I still would like give the password manually but this is the best I found.

Comment: Did you add `/usr/bin/mysql` to `/etc/shells` ?

Comment: No, but the problem is not that mysql is not running, but that I don't know how to provide the password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setup a `$HOME/.my.cnf` file for the user

```
[client]
host=localhost
user=mysqluser
password=mysqlpass
```

then set a bash as login shell and put the following in `$HOME/.bashrc`

```
exec mysql --host=localhost dbname
```

that should do what you want, while the user in question just has to give one password (the system account password on login).

`exec` replaces the shell process with the mysql process.

If this does not work as expected, you may need to adjust `$HOME/.bash_profile` to source `.bashrc`:

```
[[ -f ~/.bashrc ]] && . ~/.bashrc
```

It might be enough to provide an appropriate `.my.cnf` and setting `/usr/bin/mysql` as shell, but this way you can pass arbitrary commandline options/flags to the mysql client.

Comment: you can indeed use .my.cnf using mysql as your shell

Answer (score 1):

You can do that by editing the user's account details in the /etc/passwd  and change the default shell.

Comment: Then it's not clear what the problem is.  Do you want to have the mysql and Linux passwords synchronized?

Answer (score 1):

You need a login password (unless you set up `ssh` appropriately). Use the following command: `sudo passwd` *username* to change that login password.

You also need a mysql password. Use [SET PASSWORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/set-password.html) *Mysql* request.

If you want the user to be connected to some fixed database with some fixed password, code a small C wrapper (then, make the executable only executable by your Unix user) doing [mysql_real_connect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-real-connect.html), or calling some `exec` function for  `mysql --user=`*username* `--password=`*password*  *databasename* but I don't recommend doiing the later (because `ps aux` will show the password, and that is a security risk).

Perhaps, since MySQL is free software, you could customize the source code of `mysql` for your particular needs.

Perhaps using a [restricted shell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) and *carefully* configuring it is better.

Comment: Sorry, obviously my question is to unspecific